# Usar variável em 2 arquivos php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um pequeno problema ao tentar usar 1 variavel que vem de outro arquivo php. 
Ex: Tenho um arquivo conexão onde tenho todos os dados sobre o banco, porem no arquivo de inserir preciso usar uma das variaveis do arquivo de conexão na função mysqli(); como faço para poder usar essa variavel em outros arquivos como um extend por exemplo?

```
<?php 

$server = "127.0.0.1"; 
$banco = "Crud"; 
$usuario = "root"; 
$senha = "";

$conexaoDB = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $senha); 
$conexaoDB = mysqli_select_db($conexaoDB,"$banco");
if (!$conexaoDB) {
    echo "Erro, não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados"; exit;
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta fazeres assim:

> Ficheiro1.php

```
<?php 
$server = "127.0.0.1"; 
$banco = "Crud"; 
$usuario = "root"; 
$senha = "";
?>
```

> Ficheiro2.php

```
<?php
include 'Ficheiro1.php';
$conexaoDB = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $senha); 
$conexaoDB = mysqli_select_db($conexaoDB,"$banco");
if (!$conexaoDB) 
{
  echo "Erro, não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados"; 
  exit;
} 
?>
```

Comment: Tentei da seguinte forma porém ainda não consegui, vou mandar o código.

Comment: Já alterei para o teu código.

Comment: Já alterei para o teu código.

Comment: Obg pedro, estava observando e reparei que o erro foi bobo, eu n estava conectando e nem escolhendo o banco. acho que o sono começou a atrapalhar, rs !